# Sublime Text 2: Find all 8 digit sequences between slashes and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have an SQL file loaded up in Sublime Text 2 that has hundreds of strings I need to find and replace. I've been doing them one by one because I couldn't find a [regex example](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/02/28/sublime_text_regex_cheat_sheet/) and I don't know a lot about regex.

In my file, there are URL's similar to:

```
https://cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/20125258/image1.jpg

https://cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/13440323/image-ex2.jpg

https://cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/92383422/my-image3.jpg
```

and so on...

Is there a way to find and select all of the 8 number sequences located before the image file names so I can delete them?

Comment: You should avoid showing code and data at links, as links have a tendency to be broken, making your question meaningless. Even worse is for the links to point to pictures of code or data. Are you expecting readers to key in that information to demonstrate solutions they propose?…

Comment: …Instead, provide text containing one or more *small* examples (which readers can cut-and-paste), and for each show the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Never fails that as soon as I post a question I find the answer.  For anyone else looking for something similar:

The first bracket matches all slashes `[/]`
The parenthesis capture the group, in this case the group of numbers `([0-9])`
The `[0-9]` searches the range of numbers between 0 and 9
`{8}` is the quantifier, it's there so we look for a group of 8 numbers

That said, My expression I needed was `[/]([0-9]){8}[/]` which will select all groups of 8 numbers between slashes like:

https://cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05**/20125258/**image1.jpg

https://cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10**/13440323/**image-ex2.jpg

https://cdn.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01**/92383422/**my-image3.jpg

For what it's worth, this site helped me a lot with writing this and testing it https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```php
/\d{8}/
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/sPLT7b/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                       '/'
```

If you would like to exclude slashes:

```
(?<=/)\d{8}(?=/)
```

See [another regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/sPLT7b/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```